# How do I make nested regroups in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates

I've got the following situation in this system:
Each category of products has many subcategories, and each subcategory has many products under it.
I'm trying to make a product searh, which returns a list, and in my template, I show an overview of the results, like this:

```
Cellphones
    Dumbphones (2 results)
    Smartphones (3 results)
Monitors
    CRT (1 result)
    LCD (3 results)
```

I'm my template I have only the list of products. I've tryed many combinations of nested regroups, without success. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you use something like django-mptt?

Comment: No, I just started learning django.

Comment: Do you have a Category model and a Subcategory model or just a tree of Category?

Comment: I have Category and Subcategory models. I don't really think it's the best way since both are dead simple models, if there's a better way to do this, let me know.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
<div>    
...
{% regroup results|dictsort:"subcategory.category" by subcategory.category as categories %}
<ul>
    {% for category in categories %}
    <li>{{ category.grouper }}
        {% regroup category.list|dictsort:"subcategory" by subcategory as subcategories %}
        <ul>
            {% for subcategory in subcategories %}
                <li>{{ subcategory.grouper }}
                    <!--The same way you can render a subcategory.list which is the prosucts list-->
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
acceptance_report.company as companies %}
...
</div>
```